# curl keep-alive not working when getting error 404

Tags: curl

I use curl with C++.
I perform all the requests on the same handle so curl uses always the same connection.
But in cases when server returns 404 AND the next request is very soon, curl does it with a new connection.
Is there a special reason why?
Is there a way to configure the connection to be consistent also in this case?

Answer (score 1):

It is probably not curl closing the connection, it is the web server...
My observation is that most web servers are closing the connection regardless of the keep-alive setting if the response code is 4xx. For example:

```
$ telnet myserver 80
Trying myserver...
Connected to myserver.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /foo HTTP/1.1
Host: myserver:80
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

HTTP/1.1 401 [ISS.0084.9004] Access Denied
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Integration Server", encoding="UTF-8"
Content-Length: 48

<h4>Access Denied</h4>
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

The cue here is "Connection closed by foreign host."

Answer (score 0):

Only one thing comes to me - peek&review the headers that are included in that 404 response. It might happen that the server emits a `Connection: close` header, ie.:

```
# response example copied from http://php.net/manual/en/eventhttp.bind.php

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 13 Mar 2013 04:14:41 GMT
Content-Length: 149
Connection: close
```

the curl library would probably obey that

Comment: Cool! I'm glad that you discovered the cause. Would you mind marking the question as answered/accepted/solved? :)